# Problems UEFI booting after software update

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I have an Acer Extensa 2511 where I installed Ubuntu MATE 16.04
(Windows is not installed)
Today, after a software update (which required a reboot), the reboot failed.

I ran boot-repair.

After that, and after trying and changing boot settings in the
setup (for example I indicated grubx64.efi or shimx64.efi as a reliable file), now the situation is :

- on start I get a blue window saying "no bootable device"
- but, if I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the system goes to a "boot menu":
- there, if I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again on "unknown HDD"...I finally get the GRUB menu, which seems to reliably start Ubuntu

Now: Grub seems to work correctly, but the system doesn't
go directly to the appropriate EFI file ?!?

The system seems to believe that the disk is not bootable when it in fact it is ?!?

I'd like this computer to go directly to the GRUB menu without having to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice

Can you help me?

I add that I have two separated partitions: `/boot/efi` on `/dev/sda1` (fat32) and `/boot` on `/dev/sda2`

...in fact I ran boot-repair three times,
AFTER THE FIRST TIME the report is:   [here](http://paste2.org/WBdX6DJh)
PRESENT SITUATION (I ran it again, ASKING TO ONLY WRITE ITS REPORT)
[here](http://paste2.org/yjsjw6nN) is the second report

What follows is the directory listing of the partition /boot/efi

```
$ ls -l /boot/efi/

total 16

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 lug 16 19:35 Boot
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 lug 16 18:06 EFI
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 lug 16 18:06 Microsoft
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 lug 16 18:06 ubuntu

$ ls -l /boot/efi/Boot/

total 1260

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1289424 lug 16 19:35 bootx64.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       0 lug 16 19:35 bootx64.efi.grb


$ ls -l /boot/efi/Microsoft/

total 4

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 lug 16 19:35 Boot

$ ls -l /boot/efi/Microsoft/Boot/

total 2520

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1289424 lug 16 19:35 bootmgfw.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       0 lug 16 19:35 bootmgfw.efi.grb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1289424 lug 16 19:35 bootx64.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       0 lug 16 19:35 bootx64.efi.grb

$ ls -l /boot/efi/ubuntu/

total 1260

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1289424 lug 16 18:06 shimx64.efi

$ ls -l /boot/efi/EFI

total 12

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 lug 16 19:35 Boot
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 lug 16 18:06 Microsoft
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 giu 23 11:09 ubuntu

$ ls -l /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/

total 1260

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1289424 lug 16 19:35 bootx64.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       0 lug 16 19:35 bootx64.efi.grb

$ ls -l /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/

total 4

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 lug 16 19:35 Boot

$ ls -l /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/

totale 2520

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1289424 lug 16 19:35 bootmgfw.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       0 lug 16 19:35 bootmgfw.efi.grb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1289424 lug 16 19:35 bootx64.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       0 lug 16 19:35 bootx64.efi.grb

$ ls -l /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/

total 3620

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 giu 23 11:08 fw
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   64352 giu 23 11:08 fwupx64.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     121 lug 16 19:35 grub.cfg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1067896 lug 16 19:35 grubx64.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1271672 lug 16 19:35 MokManager.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1289424 lug 16 19:35 shimx64.efi


$ ls -l /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/fw/

total 0
```

Comment: Your last report show no bootloaders at all in your EFI partition.  Checking the sizes, shimx64.efi is in /EFI/Boot and /EFI/Microsoft/Boot, but there is no necessary copy of grubx64.efi in the same directory.  Are you trying to boot UEFI or legacy?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which works for me:

I just sudo-copied grubx64.efi in /boot/efi/ 
(from the /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/ subdirectory),
so that now I have the file /boot/efi/grubx64.efi

Then I indicated this as a reliable file in the setup.

Now it seems to work.

Thank you, Zanna, for editing, and ubfan1 for your ready answer.